# Cisco Nexus 9300 TCAM carving

Tags: cisco, network, acl, cisco-nexus, tcam

I have `Cisco Nexus C9396PX L3` switch and i have configured bunch of ACL (inbound) on it to deny/permit traffic. now if i am trying to add more ACL then getting error that your TCAM table is full. here is the output of tcam

If you noticed line `Ingress IPv4 RACL 259 253 50.59` It is for L3 ACL and reach to 50% utilization but still i have `50%` free so why i am not able to add more rules? one thing i noticed its Ingress so may be possible i used up all Ingress entries and now whatever else which is for egress.. am i right?

Let's say i am not using any L2 function on switch and want to give `VACL` tcam size to `RACL` does that possible?

```
swt-c9396PX# show hardware access-list resource utilization

slot  1
=======



INSTANCE 0x0
-------------


         ACL Hardware Resource Utilization (Mod 1)
         ----------------------------------------------------------
                                        Used    Free    Percent
                                                        Utilization
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Ingress IPv4 PACL                       3       509     0.59
Ingress IPv4 Port QoS                   4       252     1.56
Ingress IPv4 VACL                       2       510     0.39
Ingress IPv4 RACL                       259     253     50.59
Egress IPv4 VACL                        3       509     0.59
Egress IPv4 RACL                        3       253     1.17
SUP COPP                                205     51      80.08
SUP COPP Reason Code TCAM               6       122     4.69
Redirect                                2       510     0.39
VPC Convergence                         1       255     0.39
sFlow Northstar ACL                     0       256     0.00

LOU                                     2       22      8.33
Both LOU Operands                       2
Single LOU Operands                     0
LOU L4 src port:                        1
LOU L4 dst port:                        1
LOU L3 packet len:                      0
LOU IP tos:                             0
LOU IP dscp:                            0
LOU ip precedence:                      0
LOU ip TTL:                             0
TCP Flags                               0       16      0.00

Protocol CAM                            2       244     0.81
Mac Etype/Proto CAM                     0       14      0.00

L4 op labels, Tcam 0                    0       1023    0.00
L4 op labels, Tcam 2                    1       62      1.58
L4 op labels, Tcam 6                    0       2047    0.00

Ingress Dest info table                 0       512     0.00
Egress Dest info table                  0       512     0.00


INSTANCE 0x1
-------------


         ACL Hardware Resource Utilization (Mod 1)
         ----------------------------------------------------------
                                        Used    Free    Percent
                                                        Utilization
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Ingress NS IPv4 Port QoS                1       255     0.39
Ingress NS IPv4 L3 QoS                  1       255     0.39
Ingress NS IPv4 VLAN QoS                1       255     0.39

LOU                                     0       24      0.00
Both LOU Operands                       0
Single LOU Operands                     0
LOU L4 src port:                        0
LOU L4 dst port:                        0
LOU L3 packet len:                      0
LOU IP tos:                             0
LOU IP dscp:                            0
LOU ip precedence:                      0
LOU ip TTL:                             0
TCP Flags                               0       16      0.00

Protocol CAM                            0       246     0.00
Mac Etype/Proto CAM                     0       14      0.00
```

Comment: You have some [limitations](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/6-x/security/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Security_Configuration_Guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Security_Configuration_Guide_chapter_01010.html#con_1458569). For example, "_Only 62 unique ACLs can be configured. Each ACL takes one label. If the same ACL is configured on multiple interfaces, the same label is shared. If each ACL has unique entries, the ACL labels are not shared, and the label limit is 62._"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/6-x/security/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Security_Configuration_Guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Security_Configuration_Guide_chapter_01010.html#concept_945210FB9986499285C6A00065105AC9

(Quote from documentation)
Atomic ACL Updates

By default, when a supervisor module of a Cisco Nexus 9000 Series device updates an I/O module with changes to an ACL, it performs an atomic ACL update. An atomic update does not disrupt traffic that the updated ACL applies to; however, an atomic update requires that an I/O module that receives an ACL update has enough available resources to store each updated ACL entry in addition to all pre-existing entries in the affected ACL. After the update occurs, the additional resources used for the update are freed. If the I/O module lacks the required resources, the device generates an error message and the ACL update to the I/O module fails.
If an I/O module lacks the resources required for an atomic update, you can disable atomic updates by using the no hardware access-list update atomic command; however, during the brief time required for the device to remove the preexisting ACL and implement the updated ACL, traffic that the ACL applies to is dropped by default.
If you want to permit all traffic that an ACL applies to while it receives a nonatomic update, use the hardware access-list update default-result permit command.

Paraphrasing: if you have one ACL on a Nexus which uses 51% of your TCAMS, you cannot update it without turning off atomic update because that would require 102% of your TCAMS.

Comment: That platform has a very small TCAM budget. May not be the best choice for significant ACLs. I’m curious how many lines of ACL that translates to. My self interest would encourage you to run your ACL through my ACL analyzer to look for duplicates/supersets (see profile).

Comment: Total `126` line in my access-list

Comment: Let me understand if i disable automic update and use `hardware access-list update default-result permit` in that can when i make any change in ACL does it going to disturb my traffic? I can understand it will do permit all during that ACL update but doesn't drop my traffic right?

Comment: Correct. Hopefully the time duration will be small given the small ACL.

Comment: That said, it may be best to execute the procedure the first time during non-peak hours to minimize risk.

Comment: Just first time right after that i can add/remove ACL on fly and there won't be any downtime, is that ture?

Comment: No “downtime” but you have those acls for a reason. During the short update intervals they will not be protecting your infrastructure. The duration of the first update will tell you how long that is. Networks are always under attack. You may want to discuss this with your Infosec engineer.

Comment: I am totally fine with short period of time (i am assuming that short period is in 1s or 2s) that is totally acceptable.

Comment: You could set up a continuous 1/second ping through the acl.  If it’s denied while the acl is in force that would give you an accurate measurement of the vulnerability window.

Comment: I’d love to hear what the measured vulnerability window is. Thx for the acl line number: looks like 2 TCAMs per acl.

Comment: Yesss that is true, its taking 2 TCAMs entry for single acl, i will run test soon and will post post result here.

Comment: One more question, We are not using `VACL` so why don't i take `512` slice of VACL and give it to `RACL` ?  do you think that would be good idea?

Comment: I don’t have experience with reallocating VACL TCAMs to RACL.  Need to test in lab if production is important. That type of reconfiguration may require a reboot

Comment: I did test in LAB and gave `1024` to RACL and it works but just want to make sure making `VACL` to `0` won't case any issue

Comment: Then I can’t help you any more, other than pointing out your original output does show the default VACL use. Good luck!